# Why myList = [range(1,10)] does not return a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried this:

```
myList = [range(1,10)]

print(myList)
```

and got this output:

```
range(1, 10)
```

why it did not returned a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]?

Comment: Note, to format code, indent it by four spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the example in Python3, where the `range` function returns an iterable. Therefore, you have to pass the generator to the `list` function to force the expression to give a full list:

```
l = list(range(10))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

With a generator, you can iterate over it like so:

```
 for i in function_that_yields_generator():
       #do something
```

You can also use the function `next()` to get elements from a generator. Since the range function is an iterable not an iterator, you can use this:

```
l = range(10)
new_l = iter(l)
>>next(new_l)
0
>>next(new_l)
1
>>next(new_l)
2
```

Etc.

For an iterator, you can do this:

```
>>s = function_that_yields_generator()
>>next(s)
#someval1
>>next(s)
#someval2
```

Comment: i am new to python, so from your answer i am getting is... by generator you mean that it must be called again by a function or must be used in loop ?

Comment: @mohitkaushik Please see my recent edit. Also, if this answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: @AnthonySottile Thanks for pointing that out. It is fixed now.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Please see my recent edit.